# Почему "свеч"-"свечей", но "плеч" и "печей"?

Tags: морфология

Почему родительный падеж от слова "свечи" может быть и "свечей", и "свеч" (в выражении "игра стоит свеч"), от "плечи" - только "плеч", а от "печи" - "печей"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Об окончаниях родительного падежа множественного числа — у Розенталя:

http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/57.htm

Answer (score 2):

Не стоит сравнивать. Плечо - среднего рода, свеча - женского.
Ко всему прочему, плечи - парный предмет, такие слова часто сохраняют исторические формы словоизменения, внешне ничем не мотивированные (ср: глаз, ушей, рогов).

А вообще не стоит искать формальных объяснений для подобных явлений. Тут чаще всего дело ограничивается ссылкой на исторически сложившееся употребление.